# Apply specific tax only if products price more than 110

Tags: tax, magento-2.0.7

Is there any way to create tax rule based on  <del>cart total</del> product unit price? I need to implement  New York 4% state tax for purchase price over $110. Thanks.

A little clarification. Tax should be apply based on unit price, not total price.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box Magento does not provide the ability to apply a tax rate based on the cart total. You would need to handle this programmatically or use a third-party sales tax extension with support for product taxability / exemptions in New York.

Comment: Yes, I see that it should be done with custom module, but I can't find magento function that needs to be changed

Answer (score 0):

```
class TaxCalculation implements TaxCalculationInterface
{
/**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function calculateTax(
        \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsInterface $quoteDetails,
        $storeId = null,
        $round = true
    ) {
// step1 : From quote details get cart total without tax.
// if less then 110 set tax amount to 0

}
```

In short function stated above should be modified( By override or plugin) and you will get the required result.